# Handle browser back button events in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

i have this code from a article.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
            // The popstate event is fired each time when the current history entry changes.

            var r = confirm("You pressed a Back button! Are you sure?!");

            if (r == true) {
                // Call Back button programmatically as per user confirmation.
                history.back();
                // Uncomment below line to redirect to the previous page instead.
                // window.location = document.referrer // Note: IE11 is not supporting this.
            } else {
                // Stay on the current page.
                history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
            }

            history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);

        }, false);
```

where do i put this code in component in angular 2? is above code typescript compatible? I am not able to fire this event when i press back button as of now. is there any better way?

Comment: The better way is you don't need to worry about managing the history object, use angular router and it will do the job for you

Comment: even if you press back button of browser. will it handle it?

Comment: Yes.That is why it is called router module

Answer (score 5):

In angular 2 you can use `PlatformLocation` which has `onPopState` listener.

```
import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common' 

constructor(location: PlatformLocation) {

    location.onPopState(() => {

        var r = confirm("You pressed a Back button! Are you sure?!");

        if (r == true) {
            // Call Back button programmatically as per user confirmation.
            history.back();
            // Uncomment below line to redirect to the previous page instead.
            // window.location = document.referrer // Note: IE11 is not supporting this.
        } else {
            // Stay on the current page.
            history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
        }

        history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    });

}
```

Comment: The official documentation suggest the following: "This class should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use Location." https://angular.io/api/common/Location

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to add this code anywhere in the project. Angular will take care of the back button of browser.

Comment: Angular builds single-page website. If you hit back button, you will exit whole web app, no matter where you are