# App show the droid on android phone but doesn't start the application

Tags: angular, cordova

I've been working on this tuto to bring my angular app to Android:
https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6
It seems to work fine.
But at the end, i end up with that on my screen:
[image]

How can i start my application from here?
Here is the code throwing the problem (I suppose):

```
ngOnInit(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() { 
      alert(device.platform); start
      }, false); 
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Has you copy your "dist" folder from Angular to "www" folder of Cordova?

Comment: You mean that : "To achieve that, open .angular-cli.json/angular.json in our root directory and change the value of outDir property from “dist” to “www” " ? Yes, I did ! And it's in www that there is the Angular index file with the droid...

Comment: has you make ng build --prod?

Comment: In your www folder you must have the index.html, the assets folder and the differents .js that generate angular-cli

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729751/close-angular-modal-and-remain-on-same-page-on-back-button-click/51733081#51733081 I put the code I use in Cordova -well, I use the template of VisualStudio Comunity 2017 but perhafs can help you

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't works... :'(

Comment: A simple ng build was the  solution. Thx eliseo