# Check platform.ready() is not on Capacitor app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I develop an Angular and Capacitor app. i.e. No Ionic here

How can I check this on Native platform `await this.platform.ready();`. Because I need to use the Cordova plugin on App startup like so:

*app.component.ts*

```
 constructor(
    private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) {

    this.initializeApp();
  }

private async initializeApp(): Promise<void> {

    //await this.platform.ready(); //cannot use here no Ionic
  

    if (Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('StatusBar')) { StatusBar.show(); }

    if (Capacitor.isNative) { this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT); }
  }
```

So what is the alternative here?

**Update**

The problem here is I need to use Firebase Username/pw feature. But it gives the below error on iOS device on Native build.

> [error] -
> {"code":"auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment","message":"This
> operation is not supported in the environment this application is
> running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or
> chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled."}

I saw something from google here. i.e. he says Firebase listen to the device ready event.

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/178#issuecomment-310460472

i.e.
Also the SDK will listen to 'deviceready' event. If it doesn't get that signal in like a second, it times out and assumes you are not running in Cordova environment. Also make sure you did not disable web storage as the app relies on that.

So how can I do that?

**Update 2**

npx cap ls

```
Found 0 Capacitor plugins for android:
  Found 5 Cordova plugins for android
    cordova-plugin-ionic (5.4.7)
    cordova-plugin-screen-orientation (3.0.2)
    cordova-plugin-whitelist (1.3.4)
    es6-promise-plugin (4.2.2)
    phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner (8.1.0)
  Found 0 Capacitor plugins for ios:
  Found 4 Cordova plugins for ios
    cordova-plugin-ionic (5.4.7)
    cordova-plugin-screen-orientation (3.0.2)
    es6-promise-plugin (4.2.2)
    phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner (8.1.0)
  Found 1 incompatible Cordova plugin for ios, skipped install
    cordova-plugin-whitelist (1.3.4)
[info] Listing plugins for web is not possible
```

**Update 3**

```
import { Component, HostListener, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
import { Capacitor, PluginRegistry, Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

import { ScreenSizeService } from './core/services/data/screen-size.service';
import { AuthService } from './core/services/apis/auth.service';
import { MenubarService } from './core/services/data/menubar.service';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

const { StatusBar }: PluginRegistry = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public screenSizeService: ScreenSizeService,
    public authService: AuthService,
    private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation,
    public menubarService: MenubarService,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: any) {

    this.initializeApp();
  }



  private initializeApp(): void {

 
    if (Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('StatusBar')) { StatusBar.show(); }

      
    this.doc.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

  }

  onDeviceReady(): void {
    if (Capacitor.isNative) { this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT); }
    this.authService.setFirebaseAuth();
  }

 

}
```

Comment: I'm not prety sure if this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602342/angular-6-cordova-how-to-convert-current-angular-project-to-cordova-based-pr/52603564#52603564 can help you. It's about use Cordova, wait to event deviceReady to lauch the app

Comment: @Eliseo Here no Cordova platform. Only the Capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Ionic, then you can't use `platform` because it's an Ionic feature.

If you just want to wait for `deviceready` event, then you can listen to it directly with

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
}
```

Anyway, in Capacitor you don't need to wait for deviceready.

Comment: Please see the **Update** above.

Comment: Do you have some cordova plugin installed? deviceready won't fire if there are no cordova plugins installed

Comment: Yes like so:

  `private initializeApp(): void {

     if (Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('StatusBar')) { StatusBar.show(); }

    if (Capacitor.isNative) { this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT); }

    this.authService.setFirebaseAuth(); // Problem is here on iOS native build
  }`

Comment: that's not what I've asked. If you run `npx cap ls`, do you see cordova plugins listed?

Comment: Yes, please see the **Update 2** above.

Comment: try using the event listener as explained on the answer and put the cordova plugins code in the `onDeviceReady` function

Comment: Please see the **Update 3**. It never comes to the `onDeviceReady()` method. Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @jcesarmobile is the `deviceready` event triggered by Cordova plugins?

Comment: It’s triggered by capacitor, but only if cordova plugins are installed

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks, I could not find that in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Try with Angular lifecycle hooks. It could probably be achieved with

```
ngAfterViewInit() or ngAfterViewChecked()
```

Comment: Here you can see that `import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';` it is Ionic thing. But I do not use Ionic here.

Comment: Aahh I missed that. Have you looked into ngAfterViewInit() or ngAfterViewChecked() lifecycle hooks?

Comment: Sorry, the above didn't work. Please see my **Update**.

Comment: Im just curious how did you then solve it if you didn't use Angular lifecycle hooks?

Comment: Still no solution. But you can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64467125/1077309 for more info about how Capacitor works.