# What should I use with Angular to build the android & ios apps?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova, nativescript

I mostly build web apps using angular.
Now I want to build **native** android & iOS apps using angular.
I think we can use **Cordova**, **Capacitor**, **NativeScript** to build apps using angular.
I don't want to use **ionic** due to performance issues.
I don't have much experience with these tools,

Can you please suggest what I should use with angular in 2022??

What about **Apache Cordova?**

I found [this blog](https://medium.com/codex/the-sunset-of-apache-cordova-alternatives-for-cross-platform-mobile-development-in-2022-9da34234c992) ,which says we should **avoid Cordova** in 2022.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602342/angular-6-cordova-how-to-convert-current-angular-project-to-cordova-based-pr/52603564#52603564

Comment: https://dev.to/tbsraviashara/build-a-native-app-from-angular-projects-with-capacitor-40pk

Answer (score 1):

I believe Ionic should do the work (https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app).

The only things to consider are application size and scale. At some point, Ionic became very slow and badly responsive.

Would not duplicate or copy someone's article as there is quite a lot in google explaining the pros and cons of Ionic.

Comment: Hi Vartan. I don't want to build hybrid apps, so I'm trying to avoid ionic.

Comment: Hi @VikramSapate ohh did not see this. Sorry for that.
I think the main topic to be considered is plugins) People say Capacitor does the job better. But hope someone with a better experience comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Ionic framework (Capacitor): https://ionicframework.com/

Comment: Hi Misha, thanks for your suggestion. I just updated the question. Can you please suggest one according to that ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for letting you know:

You don’t need Ionic with Capacitor.

You can use Capacitor alone with your Angular Project.