# Cordova - Angular 4- Is there any way to re-write android device back button

Tags: android, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, angular6

I am working on an application, where I already added one back icon in header on each page. But I need to achieve same functionality with device back button. Each page is getting routed with some parameters which I am not able to access in `util.js` service.

**1. app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', (evt) => this.onDeviceReady(evt), false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', (evt) => this.onResumeCall(evt), false);
    document.addEventListener('offline', this.inOfflineMode, false);
    document.addEventListener('online', this.inOnlineMode, false);
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', (evt) => this.onBackKeyDown(evt), false);
    this._config.init();
    this.analyticsService.updateAppOpenCount();
  }
```

- Here I can register backbutton event with function which is implemented in another service file.

**2. util.js**

```
public deviceBackButton(): void {
        if (window.cordova) {
            if (window.location.hash === '#/') {
               // window.history.back();
               navigator.app.backHistory();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            } else {
                window.history.back();
            }
        }

    }
```

This is a  back button handler function, implemented in util.js which is nothing but service. I am not able to inject component in this service.

Do we have any other work around so we can rewrite this back button handler in any component or page using cordova and angular 4/6?

Currently I can go back from first page but from second onwards application view getting bad.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729751/close-angular-modal-and-remain-on-same-page-on-back-button-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved issue by using HostListener...

I did in following way...

Implement below method in your controller.

```
@HostListener('window:popstate') backbuttonpressed() {
    console.log('back button pressed');
  }
```

To use `HostListener` you have to import it first.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not done something like this in angular, cordova. But I have done this in react. I have search this for cordova I found this. when user presses device back button "backbutton" event is fired try adding an event listener for this.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

yourCallbackFunction will be fired when user press device back button.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.6.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html

Comment: It's not allowing to add document.addEventListener inside angular file